# Jenkins unable to run mvn test command in pipeline stage

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, google-chrome-extension

I am using the Jenkins pipeline to test Maven cases. I have installed maven selenium and Chrome on the Ubuntu 20.04 machine.
My Jenkins stage basically runs sh 'mvn test' where the pom file is located
but it keeps getting errors like
unable to find the pom file in this directory (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/env).
Maven test command worksfine when I try to run the mvn in the directory at home.

In Jenkins, I have also used the dir command to change the directory but it's showing me an access-denied issue.

is there any way to run mvn test command in Jenkins in a pipeline stage in a specific directory?

Comment: Do you execute mvn in the correct directoy? Try debugging it by running `pwd` and `ls` in the pipeline.

Comment: When you find out where the pom.xml resides, you can either `cd` into it or run maven with a flag `-f` specifying the path of the pom.xml.

Comment: i am getting this error ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/PipeLine). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory

Comment: How have you configured the job which is executing Maven here?

Comment: Yes in the directory where POM file is located i am able to run mvn test command which works fine. but when i run this command in jenkins pipeline stage it fails. build shows error